# Who should repair this water damage?

Tags: walls, garage, water-damage

My garage has some water damage, which needs addressing (see photos below). I have a good attitude but no experience with this sort of repair. Does it make sense to try to do this myself? And if not, who do I call? A mason? A GC?

[image]
[image]
[image]

## Update

Here are photos of the wall material.

[image]
[image]

Comment: where did the water come from?

Comment: Is it wet now or are we looking at long ago dried water stains? The answer will bear on the urgency of the situation.

Comment: @jsotola Not sure, but I think that duct has something to do with it.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Both.

Comment: I see wet spots but no damage, that is a lot of moisture for condensation is that duct for air conditioning?  Heat would not cause that. Where is the duct routed?

Comment: @EdBeal No idea.

Comment: Since the duct is not in use you need to trace its path a leak may have happened in the roof and dripped on the duct, once this is dry it will be fine from what I see. Without any additional information other than the duct is not in use I would want a general contractor, they can do the roofing , or a plumbing leak , I would looking for the source a copper water pipe laying on galvanized could be the cause we just don’t know enough. Yes even a limited knowledge DIY can do both types of repairs stick your head up in the attic or trace that duct and find the water source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem is that's an uninsulated duct running in unconditioned space (the garage). Every time your AC kicks in, the cold air cools the metal which then condenses the humidity in the garage. That humidity runs down the duct as water and soaks into the drywall causing the damage you're seeing.

The fix will involve:

- removing the duct
- repairing the drywall
- reinstalling the duct *with* insulation to prevent this from happening again

Whether you should do it or hire it out would depend on:

- how comfortable are you with some mechanical skills and learning new things?

  - you indicate that you don't have experience. These aren't *difficult* things, but doing a nice job on the drywall will take time and patience.
  - you'll need good spacial relations to be able to visualize the repair necessary, draw it out, estimate your materials (hello 3rd trip to Lowes <s>this week</s> today! *don't ask me how I know*), cut, fit, fiddle, install.
- how accessible are the other ends of the duct?

  - where it disappears into the walls - you'll need access to the top at least
  - the bottom looks like you can unscrew the vertical just above the elbow
- how comfortable are you with drywall repair?

  - It's a garage, it probably doesn't have to look *too* pretty, though someone may balk at an absolute bodge job when it comes time to sell the place
- how comfortable are you with replacing bits of the duct?

  - you *may* need to extend the elbow out to get some insulation wrapped around the vertical piece. A pro probably would, if you DIY, you *might* get away with "adjusting" the existing piece a bit.
  - you'll probably want to insulate the elbow, too, or it will condense and drip
  - you'll need to get insulation into the section that goes into the ceiling

If you hire it out:

- A GC isn't a bad option, but would probably be the most expensive

  - If he doesn't have the skills, he'll handle getting an HVAC guy and a drywall guy and getting them coordinated.
- A general "handyman" type repair service would probably be good, too.

  - be sure to ask for some references and check 'em - you don't want to spend good money on more bad work.
- You could be your own "GC"

  - hire an HVAC guy to take the duct work apart (he can handle getting into the walls as necessary)
  - <s>rip out</s> cut out the damaged drywall back to the nearest stud where you've got dry, undamaged material. (This will save some time for the drywaller and probably some expense. He'll adjust your cuts as he sees necessary.)
  - hire a drywall guy to repair
  - call the HVAC guy back to reinstall the insulated duct

---

<s>The more I look at your pictures, the more convinced I become that this is concrete/block, not drywall (hence your mention of "mason", I suppose). In that case, replace all mentions above of "drywall guy" with "mason".</s>

Personally, I've done a *lot* of projects on my house, but I'm not certain I'd want to take on this level of masonry repair, especially as a "first house project". Others may indicate that it's a fairly straightforward masonry fix. If so, I might feel confident enough to take on, you may too...

Based on the last two images added, that's definitely plaster over drywall. They drywall repairs are simple enough. Doing the plaster on top is a bit more work and skill, but you've got the fact that it's a "rough" and "random" pattern working for you - it doesn't have to be perfect to blend in well enough, and if you really don't like it, you can sand the plaster back off (making a *huge* mess) and try again (just don't sand through the paper of the drywall).

**The most important part** is finding the source of the leak and getting that fixed. Until you do that, the rest is just putting a bandaid on a sinking ship. If left unresolved for too long, you'll end up damaging framing, not just the drywall. If that happens, you're in for a fairly large repair bill. Much cheaper to track it down now, even if that means hiring someone.

Comment: I don’t see any damage just some wet spots. If it is condensation from the AC causing condensation, adding insulation to the duct is all that is needed.

Comment: @EdBeal in the first image, the plaster/drywall does seem to be falling off. Also, the answer was written with the assumption that it was drywall, and that this much water _will_ damage drywall. The realization that it may be plaster/masonry came later (as noted by the comment at the end). The amount of moisture _could_ be enough to cause the surface layer of plaster to be coming off whatever's supporting it. Hard to know without being physically present.

Comment: @FreeMan The home inspection report says the wall is gypsum, for what that's worth. I believe that duct was built for a heating system that no longer functions, but I'm not sure about that. In any case there's never anything running through that duct.

Comment: @crmdgn in a comment on your OP, you indicate that this is partially prior damage, but that the wall is _currently_ damp in these spots. If this is really unused duct, then removing it (simply cutting back below wall/ceiling level) will be sufficient for that, but you'll still need to identify the source of water. Are there other wet/damp spots in the garage, or is it just here?

Comment: "Gypsum" could be gypsum board (i.e. drywall) or it could be gypsum cement as a skim coat over some other backing material. How old is the house/garage construction (if added later)?

Comment: @FreeMan Water is just there; appears to be coming down from above. I'm worried there might be a problem with the exhaust end of the duct; we had the roof done in the fall, but that didn't fix the leak (obviously). Walls might be drywall covered with stucco/plaster? Added photos above; see what you think.

Comment: @crmdgn see the updates at the end. I agree with Ed Beal's assessment in his comment on your OP - find the source of the leak & fix that _first_. Then take care of this while it's still just cosmetic.

Comment: That looks like Sheetrock with a skim coat, sometimes sand is at Ted for a tougher / plaster like texture. I would be looking in the ceiling for the leak.